# For a better javascript object format pattern

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript object transformation

```
const offers = [{id:1, libelle:'foo'},{id:1, libelle:'num'},{id:1, libelle:'bar'}];
const formated = offers.map(obj => {
  const rObj = {};
  rObj.value = obj.id;
  rObj.label = obj.libelle;
  rObj.name = `Offre ${obj.id}`;
  return rObj;
});
```

My intuition tell me that this code can be better written, am I right ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: You are right...

Comment: This question would be better if you could objectively define what "better" would be.  Maybe highlight what you don't like about it (what triggered your intuition?) and then ask how to address those specific issues, rather than just saying, "this could be better, right?"  For example mention that perhaps you don't like repeating `rObj.` or `obj.` and that you are looking for more economical or concise syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shortened using destructuring into a one-liner:

```js
const offers = [
  { id:1, libelle:'foo' },
  { id:1, libelle:'num' },
  { id:1, libelle:'bar' }
];

const formated = offers.map(({ id: value, libelle: label }) => ({ value, label, name: `Offre ${value}` }));

console.log(formated);
```

Comment: ok thanks for pointing the right direction

Comment: @Jqui please mark the answer as the solution if it solves the problem to close the question

Answer (score 0):

```js
const offers = [{id:1, libelle:'foo'},{id:1, libelle:'num'},{id:1, libelle:'bar'}];

const formatted = offers.map(({id, libelle}) => ({value: id, label: libelle, name: `Offre ${id}`}));

console.log(formatted);
```